# How to loop over data and create structure with unique keys?

Tags: javascript, sql, coldfusion, structure, sybase

I have set of data that looks like this:

```
 PRODUCT_ID PRODUCT_DESC TYPE_ID
    2          Meat         1
    2          Pasta        2
    2          Milk         3
    2          Bread        4
    2          Fruit        11
    3          Meat         1
    3          Pasta        2
    3          Milk         3
    3          Bread        4
    3          Herbs        5
    3          Vegetables   6
    3          Beer         7
    3          Wine         8
    3          Brandy       9
    3          Juice        10
    3          Fruit        11
    3          Soda         12
    4          Meat         1
    4          Pasta        2
    4          Milk         3
    4          Bread        4
    4          Fruit        11
    5          Meat         1
    5          Pasta        2
    5          Milk         3
    5          Bread        4
    5          Herbs        5
    5          Vegetables   6
    5          Beer         7
    5          Wine         8
    5          Brandy       9
    5          Juice        10
    5          Fruit        11
    5          Soda         12
    6          Pasta        2
    6          Herbs        5
    6          Vegetables   6
    6          Beer         7
    6          Wine         8
    6          Brandy       9
    6          Juice        10
    6          Soda         12
    7          Pasta        2
    7          Herbs        5
    7          Vegetables   6
    7          Beer         7
    7          Wine         8
    7          Brandy       9
    7          Juice        10
    7          Soda         12
```

The data above should be grouped by Product id. Here is example of how I would like to organize the data:

```
PRODUCT ID
2          TYPE_ID      1,2,3,4,11
           PRODUCT_DESC Meat,Pasta,Milk,Bread,Fruit
3          TYPE_ID      1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
           PRODUCT_DESC Meat,Pasta,Milk,Bread,Herbs,Vegetables,Beer,Wine,Brandy,Juice,Fruit,Soda
4          TYPE_ID      1,2,3,4,11
           PRODUCT_DESC Meat,Pasta,Milk,Bread,Fruit
5          TYPE_ID      1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
           PRODUCT_DESC Meat,Pasta,Milk,Bread,Herbs,Vegetables,Beer,Wine,Brandy,Juice,Fruit,Soda
6          TYPE_ID      2,5,6,7,8,9,10,12
           PRODUCT_DESC Pasta,Herbs,Vegetables,Beer,Wine,Brandy,Juice,Soda
7          TYPE_ID      2,5,6,7,8,9,10,12
           PRODUCT_DESC Pasta,Herbs,Vegetables,Beer,Wine,Brandy,Juice,Soda
```

The example above basically groups the data items by product id and then creates list for product description and type. I'm wondering what is the best way to achieve this? I know that one way would be to loop over the data create structure and populate the keys. Then int he second iteration check if key exists int he structure and append the elements to the list.

This would work but obviously I would like to eliminate looping twice over the same set of data if possible. Also, I'm wondering if would be possible to organize the data in SQL Sybase ASE?

Here is solution that I got in ColdFusion using structure and arrays:

```
strProducts = structNew();
for ( row in qryProducts ) {
    if ( !structKeyExists(strProducts , row.product_id) ) {
        strProducts[row.product_id] = {type_id: [row.type_id], product_desc: [row.product_desc]};
    } else {
        arrayAppend(strProducts[row.product_id].type_id, row.type_id);
        arrayAppend(strProducts[row.product_id].product_desc, row.product_desc);
    }
}
```

If anyone have suggestions on how this can be accomplished please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: In ColdFusion, use the group attribute of the cfoutput tag.  See this question for an example.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24147088/how-to-output-table-results-by-using-cfoutput-group-by-date

Comment: Even without a group, you don't need multiple loops. Start with an ordered structure that stores the lists (or preferably arrays) by product id.  For each row in the query, check if the current product id exists in the structure. If it doesn't initialize it with empty lists, or arrays, i.e. `result[ product_id ] = { type : [], descrip : [] }`. Then you can safely append the type and description in the next line.

Comment: @Ageax Can you please provide example. Thank you.

Comment: @espresso_coffee - You're close, but remove the `else` condition. https://trycf.com/gist/4ecfd1376a141b2fd0f6229a2404b80f/acf2018?theme=monokai

Comment: @Ageax The difference is you are setting new empty array. In my example I was assigning value to array upon defining array.

Comment: @espresso_coffee - ah, I missed the first assigment. You sould post it as an answer when question is reopened.